# Discrepancies in how to calculate survival rates

Tags: probability, survival

I'm running a survival model right now.  Let's say that the monthly risk of dropping out of treatment is 0.046966977.  So we have 4.7 failures per 100 person-months.

Let's say we want to calculate the probability of staying IN the treatment after 1 year. I can think of two ways of doing this.

- I can calculate the inverse exponential of the hazard rate and multiply it by 12.  This will convert hazard rates into probabilities.
- I can simply get the probability of failing after 12 months, and do 1 - that probability.

In R, I get the following:

```
> (1-0.046966977)^12
[1] 0.561429712
> exp(-1 * 12 * 0.046966977)
[1] 0.5691542887
```

Note that this difference persists even after setting R to use the maximum digit precision possible, so it's not merely a rounding issue.

I can't figure out why these answers aren't identical.  What's going on?

Comment: I find it hard to follow what you are doing.  In constructing your model do you have a sample of patients?  If so you need to take right censoring account because at the time of analysis some of these patients my not have dropped out of treatment?  Are you using a parametric survival model such as exponential or Weibull  or using a a nonparametric approach?

Comment: Sorry -- I should have been clear.  I have fit an exponential model with no co-variates such that the interpretation of the constant is simply the failure rate (it's a Poisson, by the way). To answer your question -- yes, I have a sample of patients.  Time is in months.  Failure represents dropping out of treatment.  But that shouldn't be extremely relevant to the question about probability, which just relies on knowing the hazard rate (in this case 046966977)

Comment: I get everything you are saying except the censoring issue.  Don't you have to estimate the rate parameter of exponential from the data?  If you haven't waited until all patients have failures the data is incomplete.  If the study started at time 0 and you  compute your estimates at time t all you can say about the patients that haven't failed is that there time to failure is greater than t.  If t is large enough that the data is complete (all failures have occurred prior to t)  your approach should be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If people can only drop out on the last day of each month, then we decrease by .05 each month and hence after 12 months there will be $.95^{12}$.

Now let's assume that the hazard is .05, and that this remains constant. Intuitively, the number of subjects in the trial is decreasing and so is the number dropping out, as the hazard is assumed constant.

Mathematically, we can allow dropping out to occur in smaller increments of time, averaging out the decrease. Taking the limit, the number at the end of a month is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1-.05/n)^n = e^{-.05} \approx 0.9512$, and there will be $e^{-.05\cdot12}$ after 12 months.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Turns out (1+x/n)^n converges to e^x as n goes to infinity. So the exponential method used is an approximation, hence the different numbers.